# Android Studio Project Structure open failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Here is logout:

```
module editors was not disposed
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:113)
```

If I reopen my project, this error will disappear, and I can open the File Structure again.I  want to know whether it's a bug of AS or my gradle installed error?

And here is an issue that will cause above problem:

```
'ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901.aar' already disposed:'ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901.aar' already disposed:
com.intellij.openapi.util.TraceableDisposable$DisposalException: 'ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901.aar' already disposed:
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.TraceableDisposable.throwDisposalError(TraceableDisposable.java:44)
```

Android Studio Version:0.4.3 build 133.988757

Comment: Which version of studio are you using ?

Comment: Android Studio Version:0.4.3 build 133.988757

Comment: I am sure will it help or not but you can try this. Go to File >Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies and remove v7 dependency. Clean your project(Build > Clean Project) , add it again and sync with gradle.

Comment: This is just an outright bug, but I haven't seen this particular problem in production. I'm not sure how useful this question will be in the Stack Overflow format. If you have a specific set of steps to reproduce this problem, starting with a fresh launch of Android Studio, then it's worth filing a bug report at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug

Comment: Thank you,I have commit the issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65350&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: @gonjay my solution works, could you accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to fix this by deleting "gradle" folder in every module inside of the project and then clicking on File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

> So 2 steps:
>
> 1) Delete every "gradle" folder in every module inside of the project
>
> 2) Click on "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"

Comment: Just "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart" worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I had to delete all `.idea` folders.